# Remix Ethereum IDE Injected Provider - Not Finding Polygon Mumbai Testnet Metamask Wallet

Tags: ethereum, polygon, smartcontracts, remix

I'm attempting to deploy my smart contract to the polygon mumbai testnet through the Remix Ethereum IDE.

I was able to have it detect my wallet when deploying to the Ethereum Goerli testnet.

Now that I'm trying to launch it to mumbai it's not autodetecting metamask.

[image]

Here are my current settings in metamask and they're correctly setup because I've already been able to get matic from the mumbai faucet.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Was unable to determine the issue but found a temporary work around by using incognito to access remix IDE and that's now able to correctly see my metamask wallet as the injected provider.

[image]

Will find the actual fix at some other point, already tried full restart and also going into inspector application tab and removing all local & session storage data to no avail :/